# Any way to style a tag cloud widget, with lots of different class names

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I'm using WordPress to host a blog. They have a tag cloud widget. The tags are like this. The class name changes with each tag

```
<a class="tag-link-9" title="1 topic" style="font-size: 8pt;">Blah Blah</a>

<a class="tag-link-10" title="1 topic" style="font-size: 8pt;">Blah Blah X</a>
```

The parent element is `<div class="tagcloud">`

Normally, with the theme I'm using, I can add custom styles like this

```
.custom .tag-link-1- {font-size: 10px}
```

but with the class name changing each tag, I have to constantly add new styles. Is there a way to do a CSS that will capture all the tag-links independent of the number?

Comment: Is there a parent element? Can you provide it?

Comment: @Jared Farrish the tags are all contained in a <div class="tagcloud">

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258278/any-way-to-style-a-tag-cloud-widget-with-lots-of-different-class-names/6258382#6258382

Answer (score 2):

Not in a backwards compatible way, no.

CSS 3

```
a[class^='tag-link-'] {
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Comment: It is as long as you don't serve much traffic in countries like China, where IE6 is the most popular browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a numberless class to hold all the common style info.

```
.tag-link { font-size:10px; }
```

Then attach it to each element.

```
<a class="tag-link tag-link1">Link</a>
```

Comment: Remove the dots in your classes. (I submitted an edit, but don't have privileges)

Answer (score 1):

If all tags are getting the same style can you not do:

```
.tagcloud a {font-size: 10px}
```

If not please clarify your question.
Thanks!

**edit** if you are not worried about css validation you can use `.custom a {font-size:10px !important;}` to override inline styles. If using jQuery is an option, remove the inline styles: `$('.tagcloud a').removeAttr('style');`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options that will work well for you in this scenario.

**Option 1: *Use CSS Selectors***

If your tags are wrapped within some kind of a div, such that:

```
<div id="tag-cloud">
  <a class="tag-link-9" title="1 topic" style="font-size: 8pt;">Blah Blah</a>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

Use this CSS:

```
#tag-cloud a { ... } /* Each tag will be styled */
```

**Option 2: *Use jQuery!***

If you can't figure out option 1, you can always use jQuery to style the element:

```
$('a[class^="tag-link"]').css( ... );
```

Refer to [this](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for documentation on how to use the CSS function in jQuery

**Option 3: *Modify the Wordpress Widget file***

You could always go into your wordpress files and modify what gets displayed in the output. I'd recommend removing `style="font-size: 8pt;"` bit, and then using **Option 1** to style the links.

The downside to Option 3 is that you lose the Tag Cloud functionality that makes the links bigger when they appear more often. That might not matter to you, but it's something to consider.

Comment: Oh, a parent selector... Whoda thought... ;0 (note, I gave you a vote) I also like the jQuery bit.

Comment: there is a parent element, but .custom .tagcloud a {font-size: 10px} is not working. In wordpress, it says 8pt, not 8 px for some reason, but anyways, I tried both 10px and 10 pt and it's not working.

Comment: @Michael - Where does `.custom` come from? Can you post more of your markup for this particular issue?

Comment: You can't override the font-size with CSS if it's hardcoded into the HTML document. Using option 2 will allow you to set a new font-size. I added a third option to my answer, maybe that will help.

Comment: @Wex you can override inline styles with CSS by using `!important`. I included this in my answer of approximately the same time.

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't solve IE6/IE7. I like your jQuery solution though.

Comment: This will work in IE6 and 7 - the issue with `!important` in IE6 is that you can't have multiple properties in a selector. Here is an example - I would expect the background to be green and the color to be orange in IE6 and white on green everywhere else: http://jsfiddle.net/NWj67/